# how can I insert page numbers in different language in word 2010?

Tags: microsoft-word-2010, page-numbers

When I chosen Context in Numeral field in word option I can have numbers in different language font in my document. But for page number just English fonts works. I want to have page number in different language.
help please.

Comment: I think I found the answer. you can change page number language by selecting it and press clt+shift. you can change it to English by selecting the page number and press the other clt+shift. I hope it helps.

Comment: if you have a working solution, it's best to answer your own question, so that everyone can learn from it :)

Comment: What does “numbers in different language font” mean?  un, deux, trois or eins, zwei, drei?  a, b, c or I, II, III?  ١, ٢, ٣ or ߁, ߂, ߃?  “above” or “below” in languages other than English? … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Answer (score 1):

Solution is to mark the page number in header/footer then push the "Right-to-left text direction" button in Home tab. That works for me

Comment: this works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Just select the page number and change the font to your desired font of language, but make sure it is an ANSI font, UNICODE fonts DO NOT seem to work in this case. That's literally it.

If you need to add anything with the page number, change it back to your regular one.