# How to get page number in LibreOffice writer in other languages?

Tags: unicode, libreoffice-writer, page-numbers

I am trying to get non-English page number in LibreOffice writer. Specifically, I need page numbers in [Bengali](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bengali_language) (Bangla).

To begin with, I tried changing the font. I found that the auxiliary texts inserted (like Page) are set in the desired language, but the fields like `Page Number` and `Page Count` remain in English. See below,

[image]

Then I tried another approach. I tried to insert certain  page fields. I clicked  on,
`Insert->Fields->Other` and then selected `Page` from the type list. It gives me a list like this,

[image]

I see that many entries in non-English languages are there. But Bengali is not one of them.

I guessed that if I can add my entries to this list at farthest right, I will get my desired page numbers.
But that approach also [lost its way at this point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15926813/how-to-add-more-entries-to-this-field-list-in-libreoffice-writer).

I have already installed the [Bengali language pack](http://packages.ubuntu.com/hu/precise-updates/libreoffice-l10n-bn) for LibreOffice. No luck there.

Did not find anything like [this](https://superuser.com/questions/384841/how-can-i-insert-page-numbers-in-different-language-in-word-2010) as there is in MS Word for  LibreOffice. Please see the first comment.

If could give me any other suggestion, I would appreciate it.

I understand that you do not need to know how Bengali numerals look like. If you need, this image will give you the idea. The numbering follows the [Arabic system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arabic_numerals), but the notations are different from English.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I performed a quick search and found this: http://listarchives.libreoffice.org/global/users/msg28715.html

I'm quoting from that page:

> Use Format > Page and there the tab "Page". There is a drop-down list
>   "Format" in section "Layout settings". From that list use the item
>   "Native Numbering". It uses the language from "Local setting" which
>   you have set in Tools > Options > Language Settings > Languages.

I can't verify for you if it works right now, because I don't have installed on my system any hindi language, but you might want to give a try.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it did not work. In the said list, all I got are, lists like: A, B, C; I, II, III; i, ii, iii; None. I have all the necessary suggested settings from `Tools > Options > Language Settings > Languages`.

Answer (score 0):

In **libreOffice**, there are a number of page number format style to choose from, like Roman, Arabic etc., which can be accessed from **Insert>Fields>Other** in the Document tab of the Fields dialogue. There is a page in the list and there is Format section from where you can choose the required format. If you can not find a specific format like Bengali or Persian then you 
can go to **LibreOffice Writer** menu bar **Tools>Options>Language Settings>Complex Text Layout>Numerals>select** context from the list. Then change the numbering to the font you like, i.e. insert page number field with default English style and then select it and change its font to the language you desire.

Comment: I tried it, unfortunately, it did not work. Page numbers are still displayed as English numerals. There is a Bangla text preceding page number, and the font for the whole has been changed to some Bangla font.

Comment: What font are you using and please give any keyboard of bangla text font and keyboard you are using?

Comment: Font used SolaimanLipi (http://www.ekushey.org/?page/solaimanlipi), keyboard Avro (https://www.omicronlab.com/avro-keyboard.html). I am using LO Version: 4.2.8.2, 
Build ID: 420m0(Build:2) in Ubuntu.