# change language for pdf export in libreoffice calc

Tags: linux, pdf, language, libreoffice, libreoffice-calc

This must surely be obscure but I'd really like to fix it for an important document.

My system language is in one European language. Still, I managed to change all the languages for a Libreoffice Calc spreadsheet so it could be written and spell-checked in a second language.

I did select the new locale in more than one place in Calc.

However when I go to export as pdf, it exports the pdf successfully but the small inscription at the bottom "page 1", "page 2" etc is showing in the system language rather than the language I thought I set everything to for the document. The wrong word for "page"

There is nothing obvious in the pdf export to set.

Does anyone know how to fix this? The solution is probably in the gui but as I am using Linux I would also try a terminal based solution to go from .ods to .pdf with a specific language for page numbering.

Answer (score 3):

Turns out there was already an answer out there from 2013 which lead me on the right path but the solution was slightly different with my Libreoffice 7.0.4.2 :

[How to get page number in LibreOffice writer in other languages?](https://superuser.com/questions/581158/how-to-get-page-number-in-libreoffice-writer-in-other-languages)

That also links http://listarchives.libreoffice.org/global/users/msg28715.html

The solution (translating into English) is :

**Format > Page... > Footer > Edit**

..and then there are 3 panels, one of which contains your "page 1" in whatever language and you can just type over the word 'page' in the desired language.